# C# Access авторизация пользователя из бд с сохранением ID

Tags: c#, авторизация, ms-access

Необходимо создать форму авторизации пользователя с сохранением его ID из базы данных для дальнейшей работы с ним в приложении. Создал работающую форму авторизации, не подскажете как сохранить ID в зависимости от введённых логина и пароля?
Код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Project\Database.mdb");
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Database where Логин ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Пароль ='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form1 ss = new Form1();
        ss.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Неправильно введённые имя или пароль");
    }
}
```

Comment: Получите в запросе сам `ID`, а не количество записей. `Select ID from YourTable`. Плюс Вы должны получать данные не из `Database`, а из какой-либо таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо! Правда после замены на Count(*) на ID в окне авторизации всегда выходит "Неправильно введённые имя или пароль". Или ещё код надо было где-то изменить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала Вы берете `Count()` - количество полученных строк из БД. Потом проверяете условие `if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")`, т.е. если в БД есть одна строка с введенными в текстбоксы данными, то условие верно. Соответственно, когда Вы изменили свой запрос на `Select ID ...`, Вы получили конкретный `ID`, а не количество строк, поэтому условие `if` не выполняется.
Можно переделать так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Project\Database.mdb");
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select ID From YourTable where Логин ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Пароль ='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    // Проверяем, что количество строк из БД больше нуля
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        // Нужный Вам ID
        string ID = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        this.Hide();
        Form1 ss = new Form1();
        ss.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Неправильно введённые имя или пароль");
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё работает, большое спасибо!